# I am unable to access the OAuth1 Magento pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, oauth, magento-1.7

I am trying to connect my web application to my Magento OAuth1. The problem is when I try the URL //mydomain/store/oauth/initiate I get a page that says: "This webpage is not found" (Error code: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).

Here is my Apache .htaccess configuration (part of it):

```
############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    RewriteBase /store/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
```

So what am I doing wrong?

More information can be found here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html

About which URL to use.

I am not sure where the problem is coming from.

More information on my Apache .htaccess config:

```
############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
```

Clearly I am not the only one having this problem:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/296642/
- [Magento Rest API Oauth URL Returning 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472228/magento-rest-api-oauth-url-returning-404)
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/283079/

Comment: Where is the htaccess file?

Comment: probably your configuration for the app folder is set "Order deny, allow Deny from all". Please check let us know.

Comment: @JonLin it is in the store/ folder and it is the root folder of my Magento setup.

Comment: @lighthouse I just added the information you requested.