# Magento REST API response getting 404

Tags: magento, oauth

We configured the REST API user and permissions from magento admin side.
Then we tried the Authorization method with customer key and secret and got the access token and token secret.

Then we tried to call the API URL with OAuth version 1.0

```
[Magentosite]/api/rest/products
```

**but end with a 404 error.**

Also some where i found the url need to be in below format...

```
[Magentosite]/api.php?type=rest/products
```

**but end with a Invalid webservice adapter specified.**

Using magento version - 1.9.0.1

Can someone please suggest what is wrong in this end url calls ?

**It worked and got response after we put below changes in apache file**

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default

<Directory /var/www/mymagento/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: 404 means (not found) so the URL:s doesn't exists. Maybe these helps: [this](http://magento-simplified.blogspot.fi/) & [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472228/magento-rest-api-oauth-url-returning-404)

Answer (score 1):

In my case the .htaccess of the production server was missing the following line, I figured out by comparing my localhost and production server's .htacess file.

```
############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, even having my localhost properly configured, I was still receiving a 404 because in my request header I wasn't sending the content type:

Content-Type:text/xml

After this first succesfull request, I was able to consume the api, and in the next requests, the content-type wasn't necesary,even if I didn't send the proper credentials, magento returns a 503, not a 404 like before.

Answer (score 0):

You already answered to your problem, magento to access REST API, you got 404 url not found mostly link to missing to AllowOverride All in your apache config for the folder like as stated in https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29936/rest-api-returns-404

```
<Directory /var/www/html/magento/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Add your setting in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still getting the 404 after following all other advice, make sure that `MultiViews` isn't set in the Apache VirtualHost config.